# Mapsvg and AWS - viewbox parameters not defined

Tags: jquery, amazon-web-services, cloud9, mapsvg

I'm trying to use the MapSVG jquery plugin on my webpage.

An error occurs indicating that the viewbox paramters are not defined, however, these parameters appear in my HTML script.

My understanding of the error is that my server does not recognize the svg file. I am using AWS Cloud 9. Has anyone else had this problem with AWS and know how to fix it?

Thank you